# character set issue UTF-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a document,in which the word "doesn't" contains apostrophe as shown below.

[image]

When i tried to process that via a python program it is showing the word as " doesnÆt" and exiting with the error as mentioned below.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 70: invalid start byte
```

I opened the document in notepad and changed the encoding to UTF-8 from ANSI(found somewhere on the web), now it is working fine.

But can some one throw light on ,what all these things are about and how can i type the kind of apostrophe with my laptop keyboard.

Comment: Hmm, I wish you could post the text of the original "doesn't" instead of a picture. Python should have no trouble with the ASCII apostrophe. It could be that what looked like an apostrophe was actually a different, non-standard character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Word famously converts quotes to "smart-quotes", so that they properly wrap around words or point in the right direction as an apostrophe.

You haven't been exactly faithful with your copy-paste so it's hard to be sure we're talking about the same thing.

For example here's the smart-quotes compared to plain ascii:

> Doesn’t vs. Doesn't

or

> “hello” vs. "hello"

Notice how the smart quotes on the left are curlier. In your screenshot, `’` will have been mapped to the Unicode point U+2019 ('RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'). You can't easily manually type smart quotes with using a Windows key combination and typing the Unicode value.

You've then likely saved this text as in Windows-1252 (Western Europe) encoding (aka ANSI), which assigned the byte `0x92`. Then, you loaded this into Python but passed the incorrect encoding of UTF-8. That's when you saw the exception.

The way to deal with this in the future is to specify the correct encoding when opening the file in Python. E.g.

```
with io.open("myfile.txt", 'r', encoding="windows-1252") as my_file:
    my_data = my_file.read()
```